# NoMethodError: undefined method `url_prefix=’

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

NoMethodError:
undefined method `url_prefix=’ for #RspecApiDocumentation::Configuration:0x00007f9d24133d50
Getting this error while running rspec, could anyone help me out to solve this,

adding code,

```
 config.format = [:wurl]
config.docs_dir = Rails.root.join("public", "docs")
config.url_prefix = '/docs'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you post more information? Where is your code? What is the full stack trace? If you're using any key third party libraries here, what are they? What version?

Comment: With such a vague/ambiguous question, I can only make a speculative guess at what the problem might be. Are you perhaps using the `rspec_api_documentation` gem, and only encountered this error after updating it? I googled it, and found [this PR](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation/pull/66) which removes the `url_prefix` option from version 0.9.2 of the library.

Comment: Yes I got this error after upgrading rspec_api_documentation gem.

Comment: trace: An error occurred while loading ./spec/acceptance/leads_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: config.url_prefix = '/docs'

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `url_prefix=' for #<RspecApiDocumentation::Configuration:0x00007f9d24133d50>
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /Users/chandanas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rspec_api_documentation-6.1.0/lib/rspec_api_documentation.rb:109:in `configure'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:41:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: So as per the PR I linked above, it seems that feature was dropped from the gem (in order to fully support / encourage the use of integrating another primary docs viewer, such as Raddocs).

Comment: I would say your options are: (1) Don't upgrade the library. (2) Remove that line of configuration about `url_prefix`, and consider following the README's advice and [adding one of the recommended viewers](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation#viewers).

Comment: @TomLord Thanks, suggestions and  links helped to solve the issue, but if I don't upgrade the library I will get the following error                                    
  NoMethodError:
  undefined method `backtrace_clean_patterns' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x00007fd4a1830338>
  Did you mean?  backtrace_exclusion_patterns
                 backtrace_inclusion_patterns

Comment: This seems to be because you've updated *multiple things at once*. That method was renamed [a long time ago](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/732/files). So, again, one option would be to *not update `rspec-rails`, or the option would be to update your usage of these libraries as part of the big update.

Comment: You cannot generally run `bundle update` on a project with dependencies that are 7+ years out of date, and just expect everything to work perfectly.